# Lower bound for second Chebyshev function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I was wondering is there any simple way to find nice lower bound for [second Chebyshev function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) given by formula:

$$\psi(x)=\sum_{p\le x} \left\lfloor \frac{\ln x}{\ln p} \right\rfloor\ln p$$

that is inequality without any asymptotic notation?

Answer (score 3):

Equations (3.37) and (3.14) of [Rosser and Schoenfeld](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-6/issue-1/Approximate-formulas-for-some-functions-of-prime-numbers/10.1215/ijm/1255631807.full) yield
$$
x\left( 1-\frac{1}{2\log x} \right) +0.98x^{1/2} < \psi(x)
$$
for $x \ge 563$.

That paper has other inequalities involving $\psi(x)$.

**Added:** A numerical check shows this inequality is actually valid for $x \ge 229$.

Comment: Not true, for example the inequality is false for $x=228.8$. Also, I believe you meant you checked the inequality numerically for all integer values of $x$ in the range $227\le x\le 563$ versus all $x\ge 227$?

Comment: I'm not sure what "not true" means: the entire statement or the addition? I have numerically checked that the inequality is valid for all $$x\ge 229$$, based on your comment, and updated the answer. Cheers!